# Check if text is sentences?

Tags: python

So I have a scraper that gets articles. However, it doesn't always work properly. I want to get better at checking when it doesn't work. For example, the following is something like I want it to scrape:

> Hello. This is a sequence of sentences that are put together. They don't have to follow this exact format, but something very close to this would be nice! Just basically stuff like this put together with the occasional weird formatting, which depends on what is scraped.

But I might also get something that is obviously not text:

> REGISTER | LOGIN | LOGOUT | Sign in to your account Forgot your password?  {* #signInForm *}....

Is there any python library that checks the general format of strings? Basically, I am scraping articles and want to see if the text scraped is article-y. If there isn't a python library, would the best way to go be some sort of regex matching? Is this possible to do reasonably well?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

**[edit]** if you voted to close, do you mind leaving a comment as to why? Reason being: There is no stack exchange for `NLP`. Hence, where else can I ask this question? Thanks.

Comment: Probably your best bet is to measure ratio of non-word, non-whitespace characters in text - articles will have low ratio (for arbitrarily defined "low"). This may be inadequate for articles on, say, programming or mathematics.

Comment: @ocean800 it's unlikely that you will reach a close voter by editing the question.. they probably won't check back. Reason given was *Off topic because asking for off site resource*. I guess triggered by you asking for a library that checks strings.

Comment: @kazemakase hmm.. thanks for the insight! Only part of my question asks for that however... I wasn't really expecting one to exist. I'm much more interested in learning ways to do it.

Comment: @ocean800 people often jump on individual statements :) Regardless, the question is very broad ("how to do this?") and I would not be surprised if it attracts further close votes.

Comment: @Błotosmętek Oh that is a good idea, are you suggesting doing a character by character comparison of letters to whitespace/non-word characters?

Comment: @kazemakase Right, I do understand that :( However, I think my question remains... as there is no SO for NLP questions I'm not really sure how I could make it better?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, and without seeing a lot more of your data predicting the correct way will be difficult.

That said, here's one simple strategy: split the text into words and check if it statistically looks like writing as opposed to boilerplate. For example, in English for any sufficiently long piece of writing roughly 5% of the tokens should be the word `the`. For short pieces of text this is less reliable but based on your examples above a very simple check along these lines ("do `a|an|the` make up more than 1% of the tokens?") may work.

For more sophisticated methods you can look at a list of boilerplate removal libraries [here](https://github.com/miso-belica/jusText).